# What does [{:keys [var1 var2] :as something-else] mean in Clojure argument list?

Tags: clojure

I am reading an open source project and trying to understand this function which is defined in a let statement:

```
handler (fn [{:keys [type request-id] :as msg}]
        ...
        )
```

Specifically, the argument list. What is `{:keys [type request-id] :as msg}` called, and what does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring).

This particular case is analogous to

```
(fn [msg]
  (let [type        (get msg :type)
        request-id  (get msg :request-id)]
    ...))
```